# What's important about Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism?

Tags: ethics

I would like to know what's important about Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism in ethics. Why does it matter that Cognitivists claim to know, or at least that it is possible to know, that certain moral sentences, ethical judgements, are true and certain others are false? What is important in knowing that non-cognitivists oppose this view?

One answer I found is that these theories classify mental states as beliefs and non-beliefs. I would like to know if there are other answers to my question.

Comment: Cognitivism and non-cognitivism about what? Right and wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherE I think Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism in general, Cognitivism that holds moral sentences being true or false and Non-cognitivism denying the former.

Comment: Who is "we" in this? Philosophy students? Students in general? Humans in general?

Comment: @Not_Here humans in general

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Who says that we do need to? It sounds like you're under the impression that we do need to, or some group of people think we need to, but you've never seen an argument as to *why* we need to, just people saying that we do need to. But where is that idea from? Why do you have the presupposition that we do need to? Like, if I made a question "why do we need to cut off our left legs?" that presupposes that we do need to cut off our left legs, or at the very least I believe or have heard it said that we do. I don't understand why you frame it this way.

Comment: I don't think anyone, even ethical philosophers, are of the belief that *humans in general **need*** to learn about cognitivism and non-cognitivism and I am very curious why you are under the impression that they do. Maybe "why *do* we learn about them" would make more sense.

Comment: @Not_Here then why do we learn about them?

Comment: @Celine Because it's a topic that many people find interesting and some people believe one or the other is the actual truth... There are many things that people learn about that are they don't *need* to learn about. In order to survive, you don't *need* to know any calculus, but that doesn't mean it isn't a good thing to teach it to people. I genuinely don't understand your question at this point.

Comment: @Not_Here I'm asking this question because I'm writing a paper and there I need to say what's important about Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism. I guess I should have put on the title of this thread "What's important about Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism?" Right?

Comment: @Celine. What do you see as the differences between the two? Why do you think that difference might not matter?

Comment: @MarkAndrews I didn't think that the difference might not matter. Geoffrey Thomas changed my question and I changed what he wrote. Please, see the new body of the question.

Comment: @Celine: While any good answer would take more place than this site can offer (that is why you write a whole *essay* on this), I would like to point you towards the *Oxford Handbook of Ethics*, where there is a whole subchapter (Part I, chapter 1, subchapter 5, starting page 48)  solely on (non-)cognitivism. The terms are used as the text proceeds as well. There, you find some starting point regarding literature as well.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Celine.

**Getting terms clear**

I need take up just one point in your charactersation of cognitivism in ethics. A cognitivist does not merely hold that moral sentences, ethical judgements, are true or false. Cognition comes into it; the cognitivist claims to *know*, or at least that it is possible to know, that certain moral sentences, ethical judgements, are true and certain others are false. So you miss out the cognitive element from cognitivism, the element of what we can or do know. It would be of little satisfaction to a cognitivist if moral sentences, ethical judgements, were true or false but we could not know which were which.

**Why be a cognitivist ?**

That point made, I can only add that for a variety of reasons it has seemed important to certain groups that we can know certain moral sentences, ethical judgements, to be true and others false. If, for instance, we believe that moral truths are God-given, it would seem paradoxical that God had laid down or disclosed moral truths of which we could have no knowledge. Equally some people without any religous commitment claim simply to know that certain types of action are wrong - causing unnecessary suffering, for instance. It isn't only that they don't like such suffering to be caused; they *know*, they say, that it is wrong.

**Why be an anti-cognitivist ?**

In contrast, other groups believe that moral sentences, ethical judgements, merely express emotions or attitudes (emotivism, expressivism) or embody the cultural norms of a historically specific society (conventionalism or relativism). These groups hold non-cognitivist positions. There is no question of moral sentences, ethical judgements, being true or false let alone of our knowing which are which. The concepts of truth and knowledge have no place in ethics.

**Why care either way ?**

These are hardly the only two options* but they *are* options : and one traditional task of ethics or moral philosophy, and indeed of metaphysics and epistemology, is to look for adequate reasons (if there are any) for preferring one view to the other. What would reality have to be like for it to contain moral truths (metaphysics) and how could we come to know such truths (epistemology) - **cognitivism** - and what is the point of ethics if moral sentences, ethical judgements are no more than expressions of emotions and attitudes - **non-cognitivism** ? **Non-cognitivism** still leaves room for ethical inquiry.

For instance, if moral sentences, ethical judgements, express emotions or attitudes there is the task of analysing the semantics of such sentences or judgements. Suppose my moral judgement, 'The homeless should be cleared off the streets', expresses my attitude of antagonism to the homeless, nevertheless the moral judgement, 'The homeless should be cleared off the streets', doesn't *mean* 'I am antagonistic to the homeless'. The first sentence is a statement about what should be done; the second is merely an autobiographical report. They can't **mean** the same thing but if so then, what is the semantic relation between them ? This is a question for which ethics needs help from the philosophy of language.

These vexing or challenging  questions about **cognitivism** and **non-cognitivism** are questions of the sort which philosophy addresses : as a philosopher you need to address them or, if your interests lie elsewhere than in ethics, at least to know about them.

*I have taken simple, or simply-stated, examples of cognitivist and non-cognitivist positions. This has been purely for the sake of making some major points in short order. I am fully aware that the cognitivist/ non-cognitivist debate runs into far greater subtlety, sophistication and variety than I have conveyed here.

Comment: Are you saying we need to know about Cognitivism to know what reality would be like for it to contain moral truths and how we could come to know such truths? What about non-cognitivism?

Comment: @Celine. I wasn't privileging cognitivism but will revise my answer to make it more balanced.

Comment: Could you please tell me why we need to know about non-cognitivism?

Comment: Let me change my question to this: What's important about Cognitivism and Non-cognitivism?

Comment: Hi ! I've changed and de-personalised the question, removing the 'we'. See how that goes. Best : GT

Comment: Hello GT! I changed the question.